# Loop over nested dict

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need to iterate over a complex dict and apply properties from one key to another

I have tried many possibilities, such as with_nested, and with_subelements

I have an object as such

```
group_hosts:
   - group:
      name: a
      hosts:
         - host1
         - host2
      ports:
         - 22
         - 80
   - group:
      name: b
      hosts:
         - host3
         - host4
      ports:
        - 22
        - 80
```

And, given a host, I need to associate all the ports to it (host1 will have ports 22 and 80 associated to is, for example), so that in a later moment, while iterating I can use the wait_for module to check if the ports are open

The only workaround I found was to repeat the hostname for how many ports it had (by so doing I removed an extra list to loop)

More explicitly my var object became this

```
group_hosts:
   - group:
      name: a
      hosts:
         - name: host1
           port: 80

         - name: host1
           port: 22

         - name: host2
           port: 22

         - name: host2
           port: 80



   - group:
      name: b
      hosts:
         - name: host3
           port: 20

         - name: host4
           port: 2222
```

And my play this:

```
    - name: traverse dict
      debug:
          msg: "group: {{item.0.group.name}} host is: {{item.1.name}} port is: {{item.1.port}}"

      loop: "{{ group_hosts  | subelements('group.hosts') |  list    }}"
```

But I don't like this workaround as I've had to modify the dict object by writing it in a less efficient way.

So, given the first dict object, how can I loop hosts and associate ports to them?
Meaning:
I want that given host1, I check its 22 and 80 ports, host 2 the same.

So:
hosts group a:

host1 : check ports 22, 80
host2: check ports 22, 80

hosts group b:
same as above

I already know how to "check" the ports on some host, my question is how to iterate such an object

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the dictionary. The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    hosts2: "{{ hosts2|default({})|
                combine({item.1:
                        {'name': item.0.group.name,
                         'ports': item.0.group.ports}}) }}"
  loop:  "{{ lookup('subelements', group_hosts, 'group.hosts') }}"
- debug:
    var: hosts2
```

give a dictionary that can be easily iterated.

```
"hosts2": {
    "host1": {
        "name": "a", 
        "ports": [
            22, 
            80
        ]
    }, 
    "host2": {
        "name": "a", 
        "ports": [
            22, 
            80
        ]
    }, 
    "host3": {
        "name": "b", 
        "ports": [
            22, 
            80
        ]
    }, 
    "host4": {
        "name": "b", 
        "ports": [
            22, 
            80
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this did it!!